# On relationship between cryptography and operator algebras

Tags: von-neumann-algebras, quantum-mechanics, cryptography

Does quantum cryptography connect two different areas of math operator algebras and Cryptography?

Comment: you will need to be more specific in what you are after for a useful question; since in quantum theory dynamical variables are represented by operators, the answer to your question is "yes", but that will not be very informative.